# How to print different primitive values from an object

Tags: java, tostring

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Card {

  int number;
  String suit;

  public Card(int number, String suit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.suit = suit;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] suit = {
      "Clubs",
      "Diamonds",
      "Spades",
      "Hearts"
    };

    String[] high = {
      "Jack",
      "Queen",
      "King"
    };

    ArrayList<Card> deckOfCards = new ArrayList<Card>(52);

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {

        deckOfCards.add(new Card (i+1, suit[j]));
      }
    }



    @Override
    public String toString(Card card) {

      this.suit = suit;
      this.number = number;

      String type;

      if (number < 10) {
        type = Integer.toString(number);
      }
      else {
        type = high[i-number];
      }

      return suit + " of " + type;
      }

  }
}
```

So I have the object called card and I want to print the suit (the string) and the number on it (the int) with the method at the bottom but I'm not 100% sure how to do it. Needless to say, the part at the bottom doesn't compile or work

Thanks

Comment: You should override the method `toString()` in your `Card` class.

Comment: That is exactly what this code is doing...

Comment: ToString method  should not be defined inside main method. Also method signature of toString is incorrect.

Comment: You've already asked a similar question

Answer (score 1):

This should go inside your Card class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(this.number) + " of " + this.suit;
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
currentCard.toString();
```

or print it out to the console like this:

```
System.out.println(currentCard.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

toString method doesn't take any arguments and should be inside your card object. It's a string representation of the object. The values are set by the constructor.

Place the suit and high array in your card class at the top with the other variables, so your code looks like this:

```
  int number;
  String cardSuit; //renamed this variable because you have an array with the same name  
  String[] suit = {
      "Clubs",
      "Diamonds",
      "Spades",
      "Hearts"
    };

    String[] high = {
      "Jack",
      "Queen",
      "King"
    };

@Override
public String toString()
{
      String type;

      if (number < 10) {
        type = Integer.toString(number);
      }
      else {
        type = high[i-number];
      }
      return "Suit " + this.suit + " and Number " + this.type;
}
```

Side Note: It's a good idea to make your variables private and use getters/setters to set and access them. Also, override equals as well. If you're using eclipse it can generate it for you automatically.

Comment: high[i-number] will give compile error. please check your code once again.